# two same ios apps exist in one sandbox

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-sandbox

I have an app whose last version is v1.1.1, and we have submited a new version v1.1.2 and released it on 3rd Oct.
But our users are keep reporting crash issues after updating to the latest V1.1.2. 
After done some investigation from the user's log, we've found the it is very strange, the app will crash immediately after we launch it, we can see the splash screen for less than 1 second, then it crashes. here is the log:

```
Oct  7 10:32:59 David-Narums-iPod kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[861] Container:/private/var/mobile/Applications/51E744B8-196B-4892-8CE6-DB7257ABB75A (sandbox)
Oct  7 10:32:59 David-Narums-iPod Spond[861] <Error>: objc[861]: Class  is implemented in both /var/mobile/Applications/51E744B8-196B-4892-8CE6-DB7257ABB75A/Spond.app/Spond and /var/mobile/Applications/51E744B8-196B-4892-8CE6-DB7257ABB75A/Spond.app/Spond. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct  7 10:32:59 David-Narums-iPod Spond[861] <Error>: objc[861]: Class  is implemented in both /var/mobile/Applications/51E744B8-196B-4892-8CE6-DB7257ABB75A/Spond.app/Spond and /var/mobile/Applications/51E744B8-196B-4892-8CE6-DB7257ABB75A/Spond.app/Spond. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct  7 10:33:00 David-Narums-iPod ReportCrash[863] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 861
Oct  7 10:33:00 David-Narums-iPod ReportCrash[863] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process Spond[861]
Oct  7 10:33:00 David-Narums-iPod com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.spond[0xa24b][861]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.spond[0xa24b]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Oct  7 10:33:00 David-Narums-iPod com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.spond[0xa24b]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.spond[0xa24b]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483646 seconds
Oct  7 10:33:00 David-Narums-iPod backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.spond[0xa24b]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
```

And here is the crash log:
http://pastebin.com/2ccNGEEA

After symbolication, the crash line is:

```
TapkuLibrary，Line table file: 'TKAlertCenter.m' line 199, [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
```

The strange thing is that, it works fine for new users which haven't installed our old versions before.

And for the users who have met the crash issue, they need to delete the old apps and reinstall it, then it works fine. (iOS 8 users only need to delete the app once, for iOS 7, they may need to delete and reinstall it for 3 times until it works fine)

However, we have one user who has enable apps auto udpate, the app works fine after it has been updated automatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class Foo is implemented in both MyApp and MyAppTestCase. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149673/class-foo-is-implemented-in-both-myapp-and-myapptestcase-one-of-the-two-will-be)

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report.

Comment: The wired thing is that it didn't tell which Class is duplicated, the Class name in the log is empty....