# Xcode reference a framework instead of link binary with libraries

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, ios-frameworks

When developing cocoa touch framework, how can i use code from third party framework by referencing it other then including it in the "link binary with libraries" option?

I dont want to link to binary in order to prevent symbol conflicts between hosting project and the framework (project which will use the framework)

Additionally i will need the framework code to use the hosting project reference to the third party framework, how can it be done?

Or should i take different approach for example static framework (i am not familiar with the small differences of the two)

Comment: Have you looked into whether the framework you want to use is enabled via a cocoa pod? If so you can allow Xcode to do all this for you with a pod install.

Comment: Don't know how cocoa pod work but if i import a framework with cocoa how is it different from manually doing so? The framework binaries will still be imported to my framework

Answer (score 4):

1. Select the target you want to modify and reveal its build phases.
2. Expand the Link Binary With Libraries build phase to view the frameworks currently linked by the target.
3. If the framework you want to weakly link to is listed in the Link Binary With Libraries build phase, select it, and choose Edit > Delete to remove it.
   Now you can tell the linker to use weak linking for that framework.
4. Select the target, open its Info window, and click Build.
5. To the Other Linker Flags build setting, add the following command-line option specification, where  is the name of the framework you want to weakly link to:

> ```
> -weak_framework <framework_name>
> ```

6. Build your product.

Here is a docs section for that. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html)

More specifically [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002378-107026) part.

Comment: I have tried this before, but it don't work the weak linking don't prevent the symbol conflicts

Comment: You can always call everything from framework with prefix `FrameworkName.functionName()` and there should not be conflicts.

Comment: I wish to see a solution that would work from command line for CI environment