# How can I force CocoaPods to use binary versions of Facebook and Parse SDKs?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk

I've got a large project that uses Cocoapods, whose compilation time is > 60 seconds.  A large amount of this compilation time goes towards compiling third party SDK's:  `Facebook` and `Parse`. This is because they contain the most source files.

I find myself running `pod install` quite often, especially when I want to refactor my application and maintain create test app targets as well as unit test targets that require third party dependencies.

Building the project after `pod install` causes all the SDK's get rebuilt again, even though nothing's changed about them. When done repeatedly this wastes lots of time during a refactoring process.

How can I force Cocoapods to make use of binary frameworks of those dependencies which I've already downloaded on disk, to avoid compilation?

Comment: See this link for minimizing time spent on recompilation. Reason is because pch gets touched during a `pod install` apparently. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3991

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CocoaPods Rome](https://github.com/neonichu/Rome) to generate binary frameworks which you can install yourself manually.

Comment: Interesting. Will using dynamic frameworks in this way help me solve diamond dependency problems like the one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727455/class-x-is-implemented-in-both-framework-and-application-one-of-the-two-will?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not an expert in this area I'm afraid. Dynamic frameworks should allow for multiple classes with the same symbols in the runtime.

Comment: how is this different from `CocoaPods Binary`?

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems and developed my own utility  [**Rugby**](https://github.com/swiftyfinch/Rugby).
In the current version, **Rugby** can cache all (or just some of them) pods dependencies and remove their targets from the **Pods** project.

Also,  **Rugby** doesn't change Podfile. You can use `pod install && rugby` for working with cache or just pod install for working with sources. It's without changes in git.

**Rugby** was written using **Swift** and I regularly support this open source project.

Best regards

Comment: Facing build time error for Folly, using REact native.
Error saing folly/dynamic.h file not found

Comment: @SandeepRana Hello! Please, open an issue on GitHub if the issue still presents

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CocoaPods Binary](https://guides.cocoapods.org/plugins/pre-compiling-dependencies.html) to pre-compile your Pods during `pod install`.