# How to share Firebase to iOS modules?

Tags: swift, firebase

My application has four targets and I want to use Firebase in 3 of them. How can I do it ?

What I tried:

I create the podfile like this :

```
platform: iOS, '12.3'
use_frameworks!

def firebasePods
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
end

target 'Application' do

  # Pods for Tinder1104

  firebasePods

end


target 'FeatureX' do

  # Pods for TinderiOSApp

  firebasePods

end

target 'FeatureY' do

  # Pods for TinderiOSApp

  firebasePods

end

target 'FeatureZ' do

  # Pods for TinderiOSApp


end
```

I put the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file in the Application target. The app runs but I got warnings on the console, it's similar to this post:
[Class X is implemented in both <framework> and <application> one of the two will be used, which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727455/class-x-is-implemented-in-both-framework-and-application-one-of-the-two-will)

And My app cannot connect to Firebase server even I added initialization code `FirebaseApp.configure()`. Then when I try to use Auth, my app crashes because of reason:

```
The default FIRApp instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be initialized. 
One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` 
(`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase pods are statically linked and therefore can only be linked once into your app. You either need to also statically link each `Feature` target or refactor so that Firebase is only linked once.