# "AFQueryStringPair is implemented in both" Warning while running on device

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, ios8.1

I am using AFNetworking and get following warning printed on console while running app on device but  no warning on simulator. Any help would be appreciated. Am using Xcode 6.1.1 on Yosemite for iOS 8.

objc[306]: Class AFQueryStringPair is implemented in both /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/AppName.app/AppName and /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/AppName.app/AppName. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.\

Comment: Probably you have AFNetworking added to your test target. See [Class Foo is implemented in both MyApp and MyAppTestCase. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149673/class-foo-is-implemented-in-both-myapp-and-myapptestcase-one-of-the-two-will-be)

Comment: I saw the post but in my case i don't have unit testing. There is only one target. The implemented target /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/AppName.app/AppName and /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/AppName.app/AppName is same(identical).

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem. You are probably linking to AFNetworking twice somehow. Double check that AFNetworking is only linked once in your build hierarchy.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38601024/156210) for more detail.