# iOS Framework issue: Class is implemented in both

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I'm working on an iOS framework project which is using a third-party framework classes so I added third-party framework under **Linked frameworks and libraries** section.

When I add my custom framework in my iOS app project, I'm getting this warning for each class

> objc[3139]: Class 'class_name' is implemented in both
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C131AF0F-7CF8-4360-8716-3E8A595169D6/'app_name'.app/Frameworks/'framework_name'.framework/'framework_name'
>   and
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/C131AF0F-7CF8-4360-8716-3E8A595169D6/'app_name'.app/'app_name'.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

iOS app project is also linked with that third-party framework. So I think getting this issue because my framework also contains compiled version of third-party framework.

I didn't find any proper solution for this. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this?

Is there any way i can make it work?

Comment: This might be in the Framework and not your app

Comment: What happens if you don't link the 3rd-party framework at the app level?

Comment: If i don't link 3rd-party framework at the app level, classes of 3rd-party framework that i've imported inside my framework throws error <not_found>

Comment: Do you have a class name that is the same as a class in the framework?

Comment: No, I've checked it already. All classes of my framework have different prefix.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr Don't link the third-party framework in your application target's *Build Phases*. Use `Link Frameworks Automatically` instead.

---

To make this a little more clear, let me give an example. There is a third-party framework called CrashReporter.framework. The custom framework is called HockeySDK.framework (which links to CrashReporter.framework). Then I have my application called WeatherApp (which links to HockeySDK.framework).

```
CrashReporter.framework  <---
    ^                        |
    |                        |
    |                      X X X   NO! DONT'T LINK THIS!
HockeySDK.framework          |
    ^                        |
    |                        |
    |                        |
WeatherApp  -----------------
```

I **do not** link CrashReporter.framework in the *Link Binary With Libraries* section of *Build Phases* in the WeatherApp target (even though Weather app needs CrashReproter.framework to build). I go to the *Build Settings* of the WeatherApp target and ensure `Link Frameworks Automatically` (and `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` if on iOS) is set to `Yes`.