# No such module 'XXX' inside my testing target

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I'm trying to import my main target into the test target with the new swift @testable import. But I get this error:

[image]

I also enabled testability as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787674/module-was-not-compiled-for-testing-when-using-testable) suggests.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33495757/2714702

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was with a dot in the project name. The dot must be replaced by an underscore.

Replace . for _