# Xcode Unit testing : class is implemented in both. one of the two will be used xctest

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xctestcase

I am unable to access my app classes in xctest target. Getting `"_OBJ_CLASS_$_MYClassName", reference from: objc-class-ref in TestsCase.m ld:Symbol(s) not found for acrtichecture i386.` When I add .m file in test case build phase this error is removed but while running on test cases I am getting following warning - `class is implemented in both. one of the two will be used. which is undefind xcode7 ios`.

I have read many solution over stackoverflow saying to remove .m reference from test case target's build phase but if I do it, it gives me class reference error.

In this project I have added test case target later it was not exists earlier. Is this the reason that I need to do some build setting. I have tried all things which I found over **stakoverflow** nothing has solved my problem.

Everything is working fine if I create `new project' and try to access classes in the newely created project test case class.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the reason and happy to share. Since I was adding test case target into an existing project and `Enable Testability' option was set to NO for debug mode in my project's build setting. I set it to`YES` and it solved my problem :-) Reference - [stakeoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787674/module-was-not-compiled-for-testing-when-using-testable/30792188).