# Jenkins build failed with Xcode if project have test cases

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, fastlane

**['Module was not compiled for testing' when using @testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787674/module-was-not-compiled-for-testing-when-using-testable/38897819#38897819) does not resolve this post issue.**

---

I am integrating Xcode project with CI/CD by using jenkins and fastlane. My Xcode project build success if project do not have test cases. If I added my test cases then xcode build failed in jenkins with error:

> error: module 'JenkinsFastlaneExample' was not compiled for testing

**ScreenShot of error**

> [image]

---

In one post I found [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38897819/7108457) to set scheme flag, I made same like answer but didn't work for me.

> [image]
>
> [image]

---

My test cases are also successful in Xcode 11.x , iOS 13.x. tested in iPhone XR

> [image]

---

I unable to find out why jenkins build is failed.

**Demo Repo (if needed) :** https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/ios_jenkins_example

---

**Edit:**

I also tried to disable my test cases from Xcode so that I can run my cases from mac system only and with hope jenkins will skip test bundles, but getting the same issue.

Comment: looks like your tests aren't compiling (maybe), can you run them locally?

Comment: @Scriptable Yes, It is successfull in local xcode. I added screenshot for the same.

Comment: do you have a .gitignore file?

Comment: @Scriptable Yes I have. I had selected default `.gitignore` from the github for swift project.

Comment: Theres a possibility (if i remember rightly) that your test scheme definition is being ignored by git. remove the line in the .gitignore that contains xcshareddata. do `git add .`, commit and push. then try

Comment: @Scriptable My `.gitiginore` file does not have `xcshareddata`. [My project gitignore file](https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/ios_jenkins_example/blob/master/.gitignore). Still if you wanted me to check after removing gitignore file completely, then i love to do so.

Comment: your .gitingore file looks fine. there are some tips in another thread I will link now

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Module was not compiled for testing' when using @testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787674/module-was-not-compiled-for-testing-when-using-testable)

Comment: @Scriptable I already been gone through this link (already mentioned in question) but didn't helped me. you can check same just below the error screenshot.

Comment: What command you using to run the unit tests?

Comment: @Scriptable Issue was in Jenkins config which was unnoticed by me and even Jenkins console error misleads me to the XCode project. Thanks for giving your time and effort for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jenkins, configuration was **Release**  (by default) which was unnoticed by me, after replacing it to **Debug** my build is succeeded.

**Reference Image:**

[image]

**Reference Doc:**

https://plugins.jenkins.io/xcode-plugin/

---

Special thanks to  **[Scriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/779527/scriptable)** for giving time and efforts for solving the issue.