TUIST. Framework was not compiled for testing if I add custom Configuration
I've faced with very strange issue during splitting big monolith project on submodules.
I'm trying to build EventTracking framework and add tests to it.
we have a several different servers that need to be configured with different Configurations = .debug(name: "Develop-Debug"), .debug(name: "Stage-Debug")... etc.
We have a separated framework for network management and some additional helpers(named Internal_Framework_With_Helpers and Internal_Networking_Framework accordingly)
Both Project.swift files for frameworks(Internal_Framework_With_Helpers and Internal_Networking_Framework) also contains whole list of custom configurations.
All projects generates and builds  successfully without errors.
BUT when I try to write some test for EventTracking submodule and add @testable macro to import EventTracking I'm got error Module 'EventTracking' was not compiled for testing

I've tried to remove custom configurations from EventTracking submodule's Project.swift file and generate project.
In this case I'm NOT got error Module 'EventTracking' was not compiled for testing
But my whole project stop building at all and I'm receiving a lot of errors
Here is an my EventTracking submodule Project.swift file
let project = Project(
    name: "EventTracking",
    organizationName: "com.organizationName",
    options: .options(
        automaticSchemesOptions: Project.Options.AutomaticSchemesOptions.enabled(
            targetSchemesGrouping: .byNameSuffix(
                build: [
                    "",
                    "Interface",
                    "Testing"
                ],
                test: ["Tests"],
                run: []
            ),
            codeCoverageEnabled: true,
            testingOptions: []
        )
    ),
    settings: .settings(
        base: [
            "OTHER_LDFLAGS": "$(inherited) -ObjC"
        ],
        configurations: [
            .debug(name: "Develop-Debug"),
            .debug(name: "Stage-Debug"),
            .debug(name: "Prod-Debug"),
            .debug(name: "Test1-Debug"),
            .debug(name: "Test2-Debug"),
            .debug(name: "Test3-Debug"),
            .debug(name: "Test4-Debug"),
            .release(name: "Develop-Release"),
            .release(name: "Stage-Release"),
            .release(name: "Prod-Release"),
            .release(name: "Test1-Release"),
            .release(name: "Test2-Release"),
            .release(name: "Test3-Release"),
            .release(name: "Test4-Release"),
            ],
        defaultSettings: .recommended
    ),
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "EventTracking",
            destinations: [
                .iPhone,
                .macWithiPadDesign
            ],
            product: .framework,
            bundleId: "com.organizationName.EventTracking",
            deploymentTargets: DeploymentTargets.iOS("15.0"),
            sources: .paths(
                ["Sources/**/*.swift"]
            ),
            dependencies: [
                TargetDependency.package(
                    product: "AppsFlyerLib"
                ),
                TargetDependency.project(
                    target: "Internal_Framework_With_Helpers",
                    path: .relativeToRoot("Projects/Internal_Framework_With_Helpers")
                ),
                TargetDependency.project(
                    target: "Internal_Networking_Framework",
                    path: .relativeToRoot("Projects/Internal_Networking_Framework")
                )
            ],
            settings: .settings(
                base: [
                    "DEVELOPMENT_ASSET_PATHS" : [""]
                ],
                configurations: [],
                defaultSettings: .recommended
            )
        ),
        .target(
            name: "EventTrackingTests",
            destinations: [
                .iPhone,
                .macWithiPadDesign
            ],
            product: .unitTests,
            bundleId: "com.organizationName.EventTrackingTests",
            deploymentTargets: DeploymentTargets.iOS("15.0"),
            sources: .paths(
                ["Tests/**/*.swift"]
            ),
            dependencies: [
                TargetDependency.project(
                    target: "EventTracking",
                    path: .relativeToRoot("Projects/Data/EventTracking")
                ),
                TargetDependency.project(
                    target: "Internal_TestingSupport_Framework",
                    path: .relativeToRoot("Projects/Data/Internal_TestingSupport_Framework")
                )
            ],
            settings: .settings(
                base: [
                    "DEVELOPMENT_ASSET_PATHS" : [""]
                ],
                configurations: [],
                defaultSettings: .recommended
            )
        )
        
    ],
    additionalFiles: [],
    resourceSynthesizers: [
        .assets(),
        .files(extensions: ["json"]),
    ]
)

Can any one explain me what i'm doing wrong and how I can make my EventTracking submodule testable with custom configurations
Thanks

The main issue I notice here is that the EventTracking target resides within the same project as the EventTrackingTests target.
Have you tried to consume it (from the EventTrackingTests target) as:
.target("EventTracking")

Instead of
 TargetDependency.project(
   target: "EventTracking",
   path: .relativeToRoot("Projects/Data/EventTracking")
),


I've tried to change .target("EventTracking") but no luck. still got an error "Module 'EventTracking' was not compiled for testing"

Weird, you can upload a sample project reproducing this? and share a link? You can also open an issue on Tuist github - https://github.com/tuist/tuist/issues. My last suggestion would be to look into this SO thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787674/module-was-not-compiled-for-testing-when-using-testable you might be missing the enable testability on debug builds - ENABLE_TESTABILITY=YES. Tuist suppose to add it by default, but maybe you are overriding it with some custom configuration -
.debug(name: "Develop-Debug"),
.debug(name: "Stage-Debug"),
.debug(name: "Prod-Debug"),...
